# Rails + Angularjs: Module 'ngResource' is not available

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs

I am trying to incorporate some Angularjs code into a test application, but cannot make it work. I try to make a call/interaction with the database.

Here's what I did:

Installed the `gem 'angularjs-rails'` gem.

In `application.html.erb`:

```
<html ng-app="MongoAngularApp">
  ...
  <div class="container" ng-controller="PostsCtrl">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
  ...
```

Link:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', '', :'ng-click' => "destroy(#{post.id})", :'data-confirm' => 'Are you sure?', :id => "post_#{post.id}" %>
```

The Angularjs code is in the `posts.js` file:

```
var app = angular.module('MongoAngularApp', ['ngResource']);

app.factory('Post', function($resource) {
    return $resource("posts/:id", { id: '@id' }, {
        index:   { method: 'GET', isArray: true, responseType: 'json' },
      show:    { method: 'GET', responseType: 'json' },
      update:  { method: 'PUT', responseType: 'json' }
    });
})

app.controller("PostsCtrl", function($scope, Post) {
  $scope.posts = Post.index();

  $scope.deletePost = function(index) {  
        alert("!");
    post = $scope.posts[index];
    Post.delete(post);
    $scope.posts.splice(index, 1);
  }
})
```

When I run this, in the JS console I see the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module MongoAngularApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngResource due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngResource' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

I double-checked the module name, and that's good. I tried a simple binding with Angularjs and it was working, so Angularjs should be properly loaded too.

What is wrong with `ngResource`? I checked some tutorials on the Internet and it was used just as `angular.module('angular_app_name', ['ngResource'])`.

What am I missing here?

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

I am using AngularJS `v1.4.7`

Comment: did you add it in your script tags on your index page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have both of these lines in application.js

```
//= require angular
//= require angular-resource
```